# how to show http request progress in angular10?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an `angular10` app in which i have to call an `api` in which i used to upload a file and then that api extracts information from that file and `process` each `record`. I want to show the progress in % of that `http request` because it takes some time to process each record. Currently i have my generic `function` to make `http` call like this

```
post = (url: string, body: any, isNode: boolean = true, httpOptions: any = null): Observable<any> => {
  //console.log('api Url : ',url)
  return this._http.post(this.createUrl(url, isNode), body, { headers: this.getHeaders(), ...httpOptions });
}
```

So how can i show the `progress` in `%` in `angular10`?

**Note: I don't want to show the progress based on file size because i just have to upload 1 file with `100` records approx so file size will not be large but execution time of `api` will take time. So i want to show the progress based on execution time of `http` call**

Comment: HTTP works as one request one response, there is no on-going connection that you can use to show progress in term of percentage (Unless it is processing stuff that is on client-side only)

Instead, you can write a `HTTP interceptor` in angular, and just overlay a `loading wheel` to show that something is loading.

Comment: @Darkripper i have already `interceptor` in place to show loading `spinner`. but i have to show progress in `%` bar as records are processing.

Comment: But the processing is in server-side right?

If thats the case, you can achieve the loading `%` by using socket to communicate as the `server` process the data, but its counter-intutive to do so.

Comment: @Darkripper yes. But can we implement something like that until request is going on client side so we display some percentage progress until request finishes off?

Comment: Try to take a look at web socket, you can connect each other after the server responded to the HTTP Req (file received and processing).

Then server should broadcast some message or status for every file processed.

But... its just a meaningless overhead